# How do I get a list of all CSS and JS that are attached to a page?

Tags: javascript, 8, theming

In Drupal 8, how do I get all CSS and JS that is attached to a page? In Drupal 7, I could use `drupal_add_css()` or `drupal_add_js()` without arguments, to get an array containing a list of all the files/inline added to a page.

I'm developing a module that will display a "preview" of the block on block configuration page. The method I chose is displaying the block code in a `<iframe>`, but to be properly styled, I need to output all styles with it. This is why I want to read all possible CSS/JS in this "preview" page controller.

Comment: refer https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

Comment: You can use hook_css_alter or hook_js_alter but it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I worded this poorly, I had in mind not adding assets to page but reading what assets are added to page. I will start another one with better description. Sorry.

Comment: Please, don't ask another question for the same topic; it would be closed as duplicate of this one.

Comment: I am reopening the question since it is asking how to know which JavaScript and CSS files are added to a page, not how to add them.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and ask what you actually want to achieve. Chances are that there is better way to achieve whatever it is exactly that you want to do.

Comment: Edited. Hope it will help :) .

Comment: I think @Berdir was looking for more of the _why_ do you want to get these lists? It's unusual to need them, which is possibly why there's no obvious way to get them (at least as far as I can see after a couple of minutes browsing the code). If you can share your ultimate goal, it might be easier to point you in the right direction

Comment: Exactly. What do you want to do with those files?

Comment: I added **why** part. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a list of css/js files because it is constructed very late in the render process.

However, since you want to use an iframe to achieve that goal, you can get it through the normal loading order of a drupal page.

The following is a proof of concept controller method you can use to display a block in a simplified html mode.

```
public function preview($block_id) {
  /** @var BlockInterface $block */
  $block = Block::load($block_id);

  /** @var BareHtmlPageRendererInterface $bare_html_page_renderer */
  $bare_html_page_renderer = \Drupal::service('bare_html_page_renderer');
  $content = [
    'preview-child' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block)
  ];

  return $bare_html_page_renderer->renderBarePage($content, 'preview-title', 'preview-theme');
}
```